# eliminate human interaction when installing Java

Tags: software-installation, java

This method for installing Java is not good for scripts because the `update-alternatives --config` invocation requires a human to look at a list and select an alternative.

`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jdk1.8/bin/java" 1`

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

How can I improve on this to eliminate human interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-interactive method would be to use `--set` instead of `--config`. Using your example, the commands would be:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jdk1.8/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jdk1.8/bin/java
```